# Why I can't change char array attribute of a struct?

Tags: c++, string, struct, arrays

The question is very simple but I'm confused that why the struct is behaving like this as all of its members are by default `public`, have a look at following code

```
struct Student
{
   char name[20];
}
int main()
{
   Student s;
   s.name="ahmed";
}
```

This code gives an error that name should be a modifiable lvalue.

But if I assign value in a loop `char` by `char`, then it works fine like this

```
s.name[0]='a';//works fine
```

Comment: The compiler gave an anwser already. "name should be a modifiable lvalue".

Comment: You should look into std::string for storing the name, a lot easier to use.

Comment: `Student a={"ahmed"}; s=a;` works better, but that will probably just confuse you more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C are non-assignable and non-copy-initializable and in C++ this behavior was inherited. On the right-hand side arrays decay to pointers but in your case your copy-initialization is just not allowed.

If you try this:

```
{
   char name[20];
   name="ahmed";
}
```

you're actually copy-initializing the array - **and that's disallowed**.

The only exception is initializing them with a string literal

```
 char c[] = "abc";
```

In your case you should rather use a function called **[strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)** to accomplish that:

```
{
   char name[20];
   strcpy(&name[0],"ahmed"); // Obviously make sure that there's enough space
}
```

Comment: Why does this code works fine and displays ahmed?
char name[50]="ahmed";
std::cout<<endl<<name;

Comment: @Ahmed because this is a initialization. It is nearly equivalent to `char name[] = {'a','h','m','e','d'};`

Comment: Thanks :) it's quite a while since i used C++, so having some difficulties

Comment: @mb84 You forgot the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: `&name[0]` is no different than simply `name`. I think the latter looks more clear.

Comment: @YuHao yes, you are right.

Comment: You better should advise for `strncpy()`!

Comment: The line were you wrote "WRONG" is a wrong interpretation on your part. Decay only happens on the right hand side.

Comment: Marc is right, decay only happens on RHS, arrays are just non-copy-initializable. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that you can also use strings to accomplish this task:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Student{
   string name;
};

int main()
{
   Student s;
   s.name = "ahmed";
}
```

Comment: of course i know that i can do it with string. I just wanted to know why char[] behave like this

Answer (score 2):

Structure is not a problem in your case. Arrays in C are not assignable.

Instead of `s.name = "ahmed"` , use `strcpy(s.name,"ahmed")`

Answer (score 1):

`name` is an array, and you can't assign to an array name. Instead, you should use `std::strcpy` in `cstring` to copy the contents of the C-style string.

```
std::strcpy(s.name, "ahmed");
```

Note that the problem has nothing to do with the fact that `name` is part of a `struct`. You would have the same problem with a native `char` array.

Comment: (+1) It might be worth adding that this has nothing to do with `name` being part of a `struct`.

Comment: @NPE Advice taken, added a note.

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
struct Student
{
   char *name;
};

int main()
{
   Student s;
   s.name = "ahmed";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to my code? name is a char pointer in both cases

Comment: Not really. `name` of `char name[20]` is only on the right side of an assignment a `char *` type. On the left side it isn't allowed to appear, *except* for initialization (first-time).